# Position node on anothers node geometry

Tags: scenekit

how can i put some boxes (or other nodes) on rounded geometry (based on bezier curve) so they "stick" to it with proper angle? That curved geometry can vary a lot, so calculating angle based on circle will not help me as i tried it. Another thing i tried was SCNLookAtConstraint and it behaved just like my first approach.
What can i do ? Maybe i should try some other constraint like SCNIKConstraint ?

Here's image of what i mean:
[image: box position on curved geometry]

Comment: When you say "put some boxes", is that a one time deal then you want them to stay together as it moves and rotates...  or dynamic adding and removing boxes on the curved surface on the fly?

Comment: when user taps on 2d canvas i need to stick that box on a model with coresponding x/y from that 2d canvas - it's a one time deal after that tap - no animations of parent etc. Actually i managed to do it calculating a normal of a quad bezier curve - but its not involing real geometry, just its mathematical representation.